# Android- combining projects

Tags: android, android-activity, program-entry-point, projects

Im currently working on a large project and I have built all the different modules into their own projects. Now I need to put all the modules together into one project.

I would like for the separate activities to launch upon certain button clicks and I know how to do that. What Im kind of struggling with is importing all the other child activities into the main one.

Can I just import all the source files from my modular projects into their places in the main app where they exist in their own project? Im imagining I will have to make declarations in the main activity.j file that I have to include everything but I havent built a really large project yet so some help would be much appreciated.

If anybody has any tips on importing multiple projects into one main one I would love to here from them.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention I would like to launch separate threads to handle certain parts of the apps activities....Im under the assumption that this will keep my app from freezing.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough Java experience on how packages work... if it were me, I'd probably set up a new Android Project (if you use Eclipse) and as your describing set up the Main activity (the Main Launcher) and add the other Activities to the AndroidManifest and include all of the classes in the same project. I have a feeling there is a better way to accomplish it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the projects, you want to include, to library projects and add them to the main projects settings. You need to add the services, activities from all library projects manifests to the main projects manifest.

Full qualify all names in the main project to point to the library projects. Full qualify all custom view names in ressource files.

That's all.

Comment: Ok cool I know exactly what your talking about. So Im imagining at that point I would need to set up activities launching each of the modular projects i have imported into the main app. Would it be as simple as setting up a clickable event linked to each activity?

Comment: Ok so I added the projects into the settings which took just a second but how can I launch the imported project from within the other app. Thats the step Im kind of lost on. Do I need to do what I described above and start a new activity that starts the other imported project?